# Java get POST parameters issue

Tags: java, post

I try to get POST parameters posted from a website to a Java WebApp.
The java app is using an framework called EchoStudio.

This is the Java side code:

```
ContainerContext context = (ContainerContext) getContextProperty(ContainerContext.CONTEXT_PROPERTY_NAME);

    ClientProperties clientProperties = context.getClientProperties();

    for (String s : clientProperties.getPropertyNames()) {
        System.out.println(s + " = " + clientProperties.get(s));
    }
    Iterator entries = context.getInitialRequestParameterMap().entrySet().iterator();
    while (entries.hasNext()) {
      Entry entry = (Entry) entries.next();
      System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue().toString());
    }
```

The output shows the key, but not the value(entry.getValue().toString()), I have this error for the value:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String` is thrown by the JVM when you try to cast an array kind of a class to the linear type.

In this case, attempting to cast `String -> String[]` or vice versa will cause the JVM to throw this particular exception at runtime.

I suggest you to check the type of `entry` by setting a breakpoint on the `println` statement and inspect the `entry` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `context.getInitialRequestParameterMap()` should be `Map<String, String[]>`

The `ClassCastException` is thrown because you are casting `String[]` to `String` (from the signature `[Ljava.lang.String` you can tell that is a `String[]`)

So try cast they entry.getValue() to `String[]` first